# Pipe LSP server over HTTP

Tags: docker, language-server-protocol, socat, clangd

I'm trying to pipe different LSP Servers over HTTP (to put it in docker and run in a more isolated way). But after some hours trying I stopped in a final error for my actual knowledge (and being here for my first post)

At this point I'm trying run `clangd` using `socat` command to listen **STDIN** and send input to another socat instance also running locally but listening on HTTP and passing commands to clang

command of first socat:
`socat TCP-LISTEN:8899,fork,reuseaddr EXEC:"clangd -log=verbose --background-index --limit-results=500 --limit-results=500",pty,echo=0`

command of second socat:
`socat STDIN TCP:localhost:8899`
this command is executed by LSP Client (Kate for me) and want to connect with above socat

**Note**: clangd show a error log showing that json malformed errors:
`E[22:25:24.094] JSON parse error: [103:0, byte=3165]: Expected , or } after object property`
`E[22:36:44.751] Transport error: Got signal, shutting down`

the full log:

```
# socat TCP-LISTEN:8899,fork,reuseaddr EXEC:"clangd -log=verbose --background-index --limit-results=500 --limit-results=500",pty,echo=0
clangd is a language server that provides IDE-like features to editors.

It should be used via an editor plugin rather than invoked directly. For more information, see:
        https://clangd.llvm.org/
        https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/

clangd accepts flags on the commandline, and in the CLANGD_FLAGS environment variable.

I[22:25:24.094] clangd version 15.0.7
I[22:25:24.094] Features: linux
I[22:25:24.094] PID: 26477
I[22:25:24.094] Working directory: /home/xxxxxxxx
I[22:25:24.094] argv[0]: clangd
I[22:25:24.094] argv[1]: -log=verbose
I[22:25:24.094] argv[2]: --background-index
I[22:25:24.094] argv[3]: --limit-results=500
I[22:25:24.094] argv[4]: --limit-results=500
V[22:25:24.094] User config file is /home/xxxxxxxx/.config/clangd/config.yaml
I[22:25:24.094] Starting LSP over stdin/stdout
V[22:25:24.094] <<< 

{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "initialize",
    "params": {
        "capabilities": {
            "textDocument": {
                "codeAction": {
                    "codeActionLiteralSupport": {
                        "codeActionKind": {
                            "valueSet": [
                                "quickfix",
                                "refactor",
                                "source"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "completion": {
                    "completionItem": {
                        "resolveSupport": {
                            "properties": [
                                "additionalTextEdits"
                            ]
                        },
                        "snippetSupport": true
                    }
                },
                "documentSymbol": {
                    "hierarchicalDocumentSymbolSupport": true
                },
                "hover": {
                    "contentFormat": [
                        "markdown",
                        "plaintext"
                    ]
                },
                "inlayHint": {
                    "dynamicRegistration": false
                },
                "publishDiagnostics": {
                    "relatedInformation": true
                },
                "selectionRange": {
                    "dynamicRegistration": false
                },
                "semanticTokens": {
                    "formats": [
                        "relative"
                    ],
                    "requests": {
                        "full": {
                            "delta": true
                        },
                        "range": true
                    },
                    "tokenModifiers": [
                    ],
                    "tokenTypes": [
                        "namespace",
                        "type",
                        "class",
                        "enum",
                        "interface",
                        "struct",
                        "typeParameter",
                        "parameter",
                        "variable",
                        "property",
                        "enumMember",
                        "event",
                        "function",
                        "method",
                        "macro",
                        "keyword",
                        "modifier",
                        "comment",
                        "string",
                        "number",
                        "regexp",
                        "operator"
                    ]
                },
                "synchronization": {
                    "didSave": true
                }
            },
            "window": {
                "workDoneProgress": true
            },
            "workspace": {
                "workspaceFolders": true
            }
        },
        "processId": 25220,
        "rootPath": "/home/xxxxxxxx",
        "rootUri": "file:///home/xxxxxxxx",
        "workspaceFolders": [
        ]
    }


E[22:25:24.094] JSON parse error: [103:0, byte=3165]: Expected , or } after object property
E[22:36:44.751] Transport error: Got signal, shutting down
```

Tests using typescript-language-server results on no errors, no output, no logs and anything else

**Note 2**: The JSON is broken (missing last "}") but cannot figure why, and how to solve it

Comment: I don't have any insight on your specific question, but one thing to keep in mind when trying to use clangd in this way is: clangd consumes the content of open files sent by the client, but when it comes to #included header files, the clangd process reads those from disk locally. That _may_ be fine if you have the same filesystem mounted in both places, but something to be aware of.

Comment: I already solved this problem, both socats are running locally